# PHP conditional loop to perform operations like an order matching engine

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to build a mock asset exchange in PHP. For a given asset, XYZ, below is the orderbook:

```
| buy_price | amount | sell_price | amount |
|-----------|--------|------------|--------|
|  99.3     |  100   |  99.6      |  110   |
|  99.2     |  150   |  99.7      |  170   |
|  99.1     |  125   |  99.8      |  200   |
```

Now if a user places a buy order of 400 units at **market price**, the orders will be executed as follows:

```
110 units filled at 99.6
170 units filled at 99.7
120 units filled at 99.8
```

How would I conditionally loop through open sell orders so that the buy order of 400 units are filled at different existing sell order prices in orderbook? I'd also like to store the executed trades arrays like:

```
$trade1 = ["amount" => 110, "price" => 99.6]
$trade2 = ["amount" => 170, "price" => 99.7]
$trade3 = ["amount" => 120, "price" => 99.8]
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm learning Laravel by trying to build a simple exchange. So far what I did is that users can submit order (either limit or market) through a form which is stored in DB. Then by using Laravel's `orderBy()` method I arrive at the *orderbook* shown here.

Comment: I'd argue there are more _simple_ ways of learning Laravel than this. Also, please demonstrate any attempt you have already made on this.

Comment: how can you have different quantities in the same row of the table?

Comment: If you already have the rows ordered by sell_price ascending, then just loop through and keep a count of the total. Stop when you reach the buy order count.  There's really nothing for us to do here since you're not providing any code that's broken.

Comment: I didn't think about keeping track of total. This can be considered answer. Thanks @PatrickQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really just need to keep track of how many you've credited towards the buy order as you loop through.  Then, instead of what you show as "I'd also like to store the executed trades arrays like", you use a single multi-dimensional array as opposed to multiple arrays.

```
// mock of ordered result from DB
$sellOrders = array(
    array("sell_price" => 99.6, "amount" => 110),
    array("sell_price" => 99.7, "amount" => 170),
    array("sell_price" => 99.8, "amount" => 200),
);

// this is where we keep track of total bought/sold
$purchasedCount = 0;
// this is the buy order count
$orderCount = 400;
// this is our result summary of the trades executed
$trades = array();

foreach($sellOrders as $sell)
{
    $thisPurchase = 0;
    if($orderCount - $purchasedCount >= $sell['amount'])
    {
        $thisPurchase = $sell['amount'];
        $purchasedCount += $sell['amount'];
    }
    else
    {
        $thisPurchase = $orderCount - $purchasedCount;
        $purchasedCount = $orderCount;
    }

    $trades[] = array("amount" => $thisPurchase, "price" => $sell['sell_price']);

    if($purchasedCount == $orderCount)
    {
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($trades);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fda9dee366226d7a1e7c6e21ed259364065f5fa)